# How do I compute $=\inf_{x:x\delta_1+(1-x)\delta_0 =y} I_p(x))$ ? ( using the contraction principle to get the rate funct. of the L.D.P in an example)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, large-deviation-theory

Consider the following example,

[image: ![enter image description here]

Also consider

[image]

and just in case the contraction principle is quoted below

I don't get how  they apply the contraction principle to get  $H(\alpha)=I_p(s)$

According to the theorem below, I have to compute for $y \in\mathscr Y=\mathscr M_1({0,1})$$ this expression:

$\tilde H(y)=\inf_{x:f(x)=y} I_p(x)=\inf_{x:f(x)=y} x\log(\frac{x}{p})+(1-x)\log(\frac{1-x}{1-p})$

$=\inf_{x:x\delta_1+(1-x)\delta_0 =y} x\log(\frac{x}{p})+(1-x)\log(\frac{1-x}{1-p})$.

After that, I have to compute its lower semicontinuous regularization to get $H=\tilde H_\text {lsc}$
that is

using the definition of lsc regularization:
[image]

$H(\alpha)=\tilde H_\text{lsc}(\alpha)=\sup\{\inf_{\{G\in y\}} \tilde H(y): \alpha \in G, G \text{ open}\}$
with the suggestion in the comments  $\tilde H(y)=Ip(s)$ if $y= s\delta_1+(1-s)\delta_0$

I am clueless about this computation, How do I do this?

---

Contraction principle

[image]

[image]

Comment: If $y = \alpha = s \delta_1 + (1-s)\delta_0$, the only $x$ meeting the constraint $f(x) = y $ is $x = s$. The infimum is then trivial to work out. If $y$ is not some measure supported only on $\{0,1\}$ then no $x$ meets the constraint $f(x) = y,$ so the infimum is $\infty$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321, could you elaborate  on why s is de only x that meets the constraint?

Comment: Well we must have $f(x)(\{1\}) = x  \delta_1(\{1\}) + (1-x)\delta_0(\{1\}) = x \cdot 1 + (1-x)\cdot 0 = x$. But this must equal $y(\{1\}),$ which by a similar calculation is $s$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321, How would I compute the lsc? (see last equation)

Comment: I have to consider all the G open sets in $\mathscr M_1(\{0,1\})$, which I don't know how to do

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about this. Did you figure it out? In case not: strictly speaking, talking about open sets requires a topology, which doesn't seem to have been specified. But, in this simple case, most reasonable topologies will lead to the same answer. Concretely, just take the topology generated by total variation, in which case you can reduce the optimisation over all open sets to an optimisation over one parameter.